# How to calculate the distance of a centroid to a polygon in a shape file? R

Tags: r, r-sp

I have this, and I am trying to use `gDistance` to calculate the distance between each centroid and the city of Baghdad. I am trying to do it like this:
[image: map]

```
gDistance(districts_centroids, districts@data$ADM3NAME %in% c("Baghdad"), byid=TRUE)
```

Where `district_centroids` are `Formal Class SpatialPoints`, and the `districts@data...` is basically the city of Baghdad in the `shp` file.

I get an error saying the following:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"logical"’
> In addition: Warning message:
> In RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") :
> Spatial object 1 is not projected; GEOS expects planar coordinates

I am completely new to R and I don't really know what's going on.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Could you please share the data and create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi.  I believe I answered your question as described.  If this answer is helpful, please click the up arrow next to the answer.  Regards,

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question.  After taking a look at things, it was decided the best way to answer this question was using `simple feature objects` rather than spatial objects.

The map in question looks familiar. I used the `IRQ_2_sf.rds` map which is probably the same map used and shown above.  There are other alternative ways to achieve the solution to this question. Jupyter Lab is the IDE used.

Using the Google API and the `geocode` function, the coordinates for Baghdad were retrieved.

```
baghdad <- geocode("Baghdad, Iraq", source = c("google") )

A tibble: 1 × 2
 lon         lat
<dbl>       <dbl>
44.36607    33.31524
```

Then `sf` functions were used to create the `sf column object`.

```
baghdad.sfg <- st_point(c(lon, lat), dim = "XY")
baghdad.sfc <- st_sfc(baghdad.sfg, crs = 4326)
```

Then, using the sf map named iraq, the `centroids` were created.
Note: warning message - st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data.  For this answer, the centroids will be close
enough.

```
iraq.c <- st_centroid(iraq)
```

The distance from each `centroid` to Baghdad gets determined in kilometers.

```
head(dist <- data.frame(c(st_distance(iraq.c$geom[], baghdad.sfc)/1000)))

Units: [m]
[1]  28.63250  59.61553 215.43354 323.06418 259.14509 113.55356
```

And then create a date frame that includes the names, the `centroid` geometry and the distance values. Requires some cleaning and binding.

```
distance <- c(dist$c.st_distance.iraq.c.geom....baghdad.sfc..1000.)

x <- distance[]
d_Bdad_Km <- as.numeric(str_extract(x, "[0-9]*.[0-9]."))

iraq2 <- iraq[-c(5, 8,9,10,11,12,13)] 
df_dist <- cbind(iraq2, d_Bdad_Km)      # df as desired
```

And then the outputs gets `plotted`.

```
plot(iraq$geom)
plot(iraq.c$geom, add = TRUE, col = "red")
plot(baghdad.sfc, add = TRUE, pch = 19, col = "blue")
```

Please ask if there are any follow-up questions.  The plot can be viewed at this [link:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V1WC.png)